# Kill Emacs's Async Shell Command buffer if command is terminated

Tags: emacs, elisp

Emacs does not kill the `*Async Shell Command*` buffer if the async command terminates. How can I force this behavior?

Comment: You should try asking this on the [Emacs SE Site](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Process Sentinels](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html).

The sentinel for `*Async Shell Command*` is [`shell-command-sentinel`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/simple.el#n3437).

You can [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) it:

```
(defun my-kill-buffer-when-done (process signal)
  (when (and (process-buffer process)
             (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal)))
    (kill-buffer (process-buffer process))))

(defun my-kill-async-buffer-when-done ()
  (let ((process (get-buffer-process "*Async Shell Command*")))
    (add-function :after (process-sentinel process) #'kill-buffer-when-done)))

(add-function :after #'async-shell-command #'my-kill-async-buffer-when-done)
```

PS. I did not test the above code, mostly because I think it is a horrible idea: you want to examine the content of `*Async Shell Command*` before killing it.
However, I hope reading the code and links above will help you become a more proficient Emacs user.

Comment: Than you, after reading the manual I made it work, however I am taking your advise. So I will modify the code to kill the buffer when a specific string is written into the process buffer from the process output.